# How to add an additional argument to a function passed down as a prop in React?

Tags: reactjs, function, arguments, react-props, signature

I've been wondering: When you create a function like the following:

```
const someFunction = (paramOne, paramTwo, paramThree) => {
    // some code 
}
```

And then pass it down to a component as a prop:

```
<SomeComponent somePropName={someFunction} />
```

And in said component, you call it with 2 arguments:

```
props.somePropName('value1', 'value2')
```

While the function's signature describes three arguments.
Would there be any way to 'fill in' the third argument of said function in the main component, instead of the component where it's been passed down to:

```
<SomeComponent somePropName={someFunction(passedByComponent, passedByComponent, iWantToFillThisOneInManually)} />
```

The main reason I'd want this, is because sometimes I have data available in one file and other data in the other, while I do need both in the function.

Anyone have any experience doing something like this?

Thanks in advance!

Small note: Before shaking the brain bush, I'm not entirely sure if this is even possible :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this. `paramThree` will equal `defaultValue` by default. If you specifically enter a 3rd argument when you call the function, `defaultValue` will be ignored.

```
const someFunction = (paramOne, paramTwo, paramThree = defaultValue) => {
        // some code
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But the question is actually HOW to specify the third parameter.

Comment: Sorry I am confused. Do you mean that at the point when you call `someFunction` inside of the child component, you want to specify a 3rd argument from the parent?

Comment: Yes, indeed. In the parent, there's a .map iteration that renders this child component a few times, and within the child component, it calls the function with 2 parameters. But I also need to provide the index of the iteration as the third parameter (which is only available in the parent (within the .map()). Usually one would pass the index to the component as well and use it when calling the function, but that is not an option in this specific case.

Comment: So you cannot pass the index to the child as a prop? That seems like a strange requirement

Comment: No, since the component is widely used in other pages and for other purposes. It would make things so much simpler wouldn't it :)

Comment: What if you just make the prop optional? Specify on the children that you need and then have a conditional inside the child component that uses the prop if it exists. I can show you what I mean if you want

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by creating a function with a single parameter that will encapsulate the original function (3 parameters) and set the first two parameters with some static value (const, state or whatever). Something like this:

```js
const ComponentA = () => {
  const originalFunction = (paramA, paramB, paramC) => { ... }
  return <ComponentB myFunction={originalFunction} />
}

const ComponentB = ({ myFunction }) => {
  const derivedFunction = (param) => {
    myFunction('some value', 'other value', param)
  }
  return <button onClick={() => derivedFunction('test')}>try me</button>
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming this is what you're looking for since default value doesn't seem to be what you're looking for. Maybe an example would help